# Difference between selector in jquery

Tags: jquery

Before today I considered these two selector as a same, I think they perform same action but today I stuck with problem where they behave differently. I want to know what is difference between these selector. [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pTUpv/1/)

```
$('.test p:first');

$('.test').find('p:first');
```

Comment: read that as `find the first p` in the whole collection of `$('.test')`...will only be one of them

Comment: If you're going to ask a question and provide a jsFiddle example, try to ask the same question in both, yeah?

Comment: @lonesomeday I was initially thrown off by the differing code in the fiddle as well, but overall it is the same question.  The first returns 1 element, the second returns (potentially) multiple.  In the absence of something like `:first` or `:last` these two constructs would be equivalent.  The question is simply why this isn't the case here.

Comment: @JamesMontagne It's at least potentially misleading and certainly unhelpful. When you're asking advice, that's a bad way to go about it, IMO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`find` will execute the passed selector for each element which exists in the collection it is called on.  So, looking at your code:

```
$('.test p:first')
```

`$('.test p:first')` is executed.  This will return a single `p` element which is the first one across all `.test` elements.

As opposed to:

```
$('.test').find('p:first')
```

First `$('.test')` is executed.  This will return 3 `.test` elements (based on the html in your fiddle).  Then `find` is called on this collection and will perform a find on each of these 3 elements.  So for **each** `.text` it will find the first `p`.  The result being 3 elements.

Comment: Yes, I understood also this.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is based on the returned elements,

`$('.test').find('p:first')` - returns `p:first` on all `.test`. This returns a list and filters on each elements in the list.

`$('.test p:first')` - returns `p:first` from all the `p` matched in all `.test`. This returns a single list of elements and filters from the list.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that `$('.test p:first')` selects the first `p` of **ALL** elements with `.test`.

`$('.test').find('p:first')` selects first `p` of **EACH** of elements with `.test`.

Comment: @lonesomeday `$('.test').find('p:first')` returns 3 elements, while `$('.test p:first')` returns 1.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was wrong. I can't take back my downvote now, sorry.

Comment: @charlietfl the _My guess_ thing does not really mean that I took a wild guess.

Comment: @charlietfl the first `p` of **ALL** elements matched. Just as I posted.

Comment: no...`$('.test') contains 3 elements..., then add the p slector will be 9 of those  , of those 9 <p> there is only one first

Comment: @charlietfl these are the same statements.

Comment: I read yours as saying...the first p of each...which isn't...might be misunderstanding, but doesn't read right